# Is MOND equivalent to Modified Gravity?

Tags: terminology, definition, dark-matter, modified-gravity

Usually, we consider two alternative models of dark matter: [modified newtonian dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) (MOND) and modified gravity (MOG).

My question is simple: can MOND be made equivalent to MOG or does it stand as independent, even if wrong, model?

After all, taking into account the equivalence principle, acceleration is locally equivalent to a gravitational field. So, is $a_0$ (the critical MOND parameter) also a gravitational field?

Comment: Do you have references to support your “usually we consider” statement? Do those references discuss this question?

Comment: This [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2476) from 2011 lists at least 13 different flavors of modified gravity in the abstract. Some of them (like TeVeS) are fully relativistic theories that can reproduce MOND-like behavior in the non-relativistic regime. Others have no relation to MOND at all. Therefore I believe you need to be more specific on exactly how you are defining modified gravity, in order for someone to able to describe the relationship between that form of modified gravity, and MOND.

Answer (score 2):

Modified gravity is this umbrella term that includes all non-GR theories of gravity. MOND is a modified gravity theory, but it is not equivalent to modified gravity, because there are [lots of other modified gravity theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity).

Otherwise, MOND is not a relativistic theory, so in MOND, acceleration is not equivalent to a gravitational field.